# React-native: how to save webview current web page aoutomaticaly?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, webview, android-webview

I am new in react native.
I'm trying to use WebView in my react-native app (Android). It works very good. I want, after loading web page in webview, it save as a local file automatically.
Pleas help me.

Edit: I want, app save webpage as a local file, not saving URL.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using `react-native-webview`.

There is a props call [onNavigationStateChange](https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/docs/Reference.md#onnavigationstatechange).

For example, you can save the url to `AsyncStorage`  with

```
const storeData = async (url) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(
      'lastURL',
      url
    );
  } catch (error) {
    // Error saving data
  }
};

...
<WebView
...
onNavigationStateChange={(navState) => {
    const { url } = navState;
    storeData(url)
  }}
/>
```

======= Edit =======
If you want the html only.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function App() {
  const injectedJavascript = `(function() {
      window.postMessage = function(data) {
    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(data);
    return true;
  };
  window.postMessage(new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document))
})()`
const saveHTML = (htmlString)=>{
  ...
}
  return (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
      }}>
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        injectedJavaScript={injectedJavascript}
        onMessage={e => {saveHTML(e.nativeEvent.data)}}
        source={{
          uri: 'https://google.com'
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question.‌‌But i don't want save URL. I want to save webpage in a file.

Comment: oops, sorry about it.